# Analyzing and Visualizing Stock Data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hey guys I am a Newbie in Data Science and wanted to analyze some Stock Data with python and visualize it. I already found some example to Download Data and plot it but the most Code examples I found were some years old and didn't work. 
I already wrote some Code to get some Data from Microsoft, but it didn't work for other companies and I don't know why.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import operator
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import re
from dateutil import parser
import matplotlib as style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


def getStock(symbol, start, end):

df =  pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo(symbol, start, end)

df.columns.values[-1] = 'AdjClose'
df.columns = df.columns + '_' + symbol
df['Return_%s' %symbol] = df['AdjClose_%s' %symbol].pct_change()

return df

def getStockFromQuandl(symbol, name, start, end):


import Quandl
df =  Quandl.get(symbol, trim_start = start, trim_end = end, authtoken="your token")

df.columns.values[-1] = 'AdjClose'
df.columns = df.columns + '_' + name
df['Return_%s' %name] = df['AdjClose_%s' %name].pct_change()

return df

def getStockDataFromWeb(fout, start_string, end_string):


start = parser.parse(start_string)
end = parser.parse(end_string)

nasdaq = getStock('^IXIC', start, end)
frankfurt = getStock('^GDAXI', start, end)
london = getStock('^FTSE', start, end)
paris = getStock('^FCHI', start, end)
hkong = getStock('^HSI', start, end)
nikkei = getStock('^N225', start, end)
australia = getStock('^AXJO', start, end)

djia = getStockFromQuandl("YAHOO/INDEX_DJI", 'Djia', start_string, end_string) 

out =  pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo(fout, start, end)
out.columns.values[-1] = 'AdjClose'
out.columns = out.columns + '_Out'
out['Return_Out'] = out['AdjClose_Out'].pct_change()

return [out, nasdaq, djia, frankfurt, london, paris, hkong, nikkei, australia]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.plot(msft.index, msft, label='Microsoft')
ax1.plot(short_rolling_msft.index, short_rolling_msft, label='20 aufeinanderfolgende Tage')
ax1.plot(long_rolling_msft.index, long_rolling_msft, label='100 aufeinanderfolgende Tage')
ax1.set_xlabel('Jahr')
ax1.set_ylabel('Aktienpreis ($)')
ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

Theoretically I thought it would be possible to just change MSFT to for example AAPL or TSLA to show Apple or Tesla.
When I do this I got a failure.

```
NameError: name 'aapl' is not defined
```

Can anyone explain me why this doesnt work ? I would be very thankful if you could help me with an explanation.
Btw I am using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

msft isn't defined either... I'm guessing you are missing a line along the lines of:

```
msft=getStock("MSFT", start, end)
```

Then msft or aapl would be defined as a dataframe and msft.index would make sense...